# Different rank for same numbers.. Am I missing something

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Here's the sheet which u can checkout to see whats the thing I am missing because If its the same number the rank is supposed to be same.Even If I assume there may be slight difference in decimals, I don't see one

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11dpbLYI5AqyNWCw8JVK1zWKz2J2I9t68YlM1gO9zb1E/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 0):

Add `Round()` function to your Final score formula (J column).

So new formula would be:

`J2` = `=round((E2*0.1+F2*0.45+G2*0.1+H2*0.05+I2*0.3),2)`

`J1` = `=round((E3*0.1+F3*0.45+G3*0.1+H3*0.05+I3*0.3),2)`

This rounds up your numbers by 2 decimal (hence number two after the comma) and results same rank for equal scores.